# BATCH User input to be set as variable, be checked for existence at end of script and apply command

Tags: file, variables, batch-file, input

Should be straight forward I think, well I thought it was, but having some trouble getting it to work.

Aims:-
Create automated install using various batch commands, files and software installers. In order that the user doesn't have to complete the install, a set it and forget it affair, I want them to choose from 3 options at the start of the process BUT only get applied at the end, so the one of the 3 tasks they chose is done without user input.

It's all done just having problems with the start phase.

Code:
User can choose 3 things, copy a file and start the software, don't copy a file and launch a config tool, copy and file and don't run the software (waiting on additional prep).

```
SET /P "Input=Enter a Number Choice & Press RTN: "
if '%Input%'=='1' set end1=end1
if '%Input%'=='2' set end2=end2
if '%Input%'=='3' set end3=end3
```

Here is the start menu above, as you can see the number choice 'should' be setting a variable. After this is set, the file runs, installs and does things, then comes to the end where it should run the corresponding action defined by the start menu choice So...

```
IF exist %end1% GOTO end1
IF exist %end2% GOTO end2
IF exist %end3% GOTO end3
```

However it never detects anything other than just running the first of the choices by default. Ideally if the client pressed 1,2 or 3 at the beginning, when it comes the end, it goes to the menu option related where the appropriate action is launched;

```
:end 1 "copies a file" launches software
:end 2 "starts a program"
:end 3 "copies a file in preparation for some other task"
```

Hope that makes sense. Let me know if you need more info. I have searched but probably not searching for the right thing.

If I try and echo for the presence of end1 and it says it is not defined. I'm guessing maybe error level checks would be better, but struggling with that also.

Thank you...

Comment: `IF defined end1 GOTO end1` etc.

Comment: tried this doesnt work, chose option 3 and it just opened 1

Comment: It doesn't work because you use `:end 1` instead of obvious `:end1`.

Comment: is there a specific reason to work with variables instead of just `if "%input%"=="1" goto :end1`?

Comment: Hi Just finding a way to set the answer choice to be used later after other commands have run. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EXIST` checks for the existence of a file or folder. You want `DEFINED`. http://ss64.com/nt/if.html

I'm not sure if you really need to set 3 different variables though (maybe you've done it this way to reduce the issue to simplest steps). You can restructure it a bit like this:

```
SET /P "Input=Enter a Number Choice & Press RTN: "
if '%Input%'=='1' set ending=1
if '%Input%'=='2' set ending=2
if '%Input%'=='3' set ending=3
IF %ending% EQU 1 GOTO end1
IF %ending% EQU 2 (GOTO end2) ELSE (GOTO end3)

:end1
echo ending 1
pause

:end2
echo ending 2
pause

:end3
echo ending 3
pause
```

This code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

OK been fiddling, this works:

```
SET /P "Input=Enter a Number Choice & Press RTN: "
if '%Input%'=='1' set ending=1
if '%Input%'=='2' set ending=2
if '%Input%'=='3' set ending=3

~things happen~

color 1f
IF %ending% EQU 1 GOTO end1
IF %ending% EQU 2 (GOTO end2) ELSE (GOTO end3)
```

All three menu options behave!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that `end1, end2, end3` are defined elsewhere in the batch as folder paths, try this:

```
@echo off
set "mes1=Enter a Number Choice and Press RTN"
choice /c 123 /m "%mes1%" /t 10 /d 1
if %errorlevel% equ 3 (set disk=end3
) else if %errorlevel% equ 2 (set "disk=end2
) else (set disk=end1)

if exist "%disk%" (
   if %disk%==%end1% (goto :end_1
   ) else if %disk%==%end2% (goto :end_2
   ) else if %disk%==%end3% (goto :end_3)
::some code here

:end_1 rem "copies a file" launches software
:end_2 rem "starts a program"
:end_3 rem "copies a file in preparation for some other task"
```

If you don't use drive paths, try this:

```
SET /P "Input=Enter a Number Choice & Press RTN: "
if '%Input%'=='1' (set ending=1
) else if '%Input%'=='2' (set ending=2
) else if '%Input%'=='3' (set ending=3)
if defined ending (GOTO :process%ending%) else (goto :end)
:: put some code here

:process1 rem "copies a file" launches software
:process2 rem "starts a program"
:process3 rem "copies a file in preparation for some other task"

:end
timeout 5 >nul
exit /b
```